# Portage on Gentoo how to view available software versions?

Tags: gentoo, emerge

I would like to install program foo using `emerge` on a Gentoo system; so I simply use `emerge foo` to install and portage selects the most current version of that software that's in its repository. If I know the version number and the naming covnention, I can do `emerge =foo.1.2` and use `eselect` to chose what the currently inforce package is out of the installed ones, if the package supports it.

But what if I don't know the version number or naming convention and just want a list of what's versions of foo are available to me? I don't see an emerge option that does this and snooping around under `/usr/portage` doesn't yield me anything.

Bonus: Is there anyway to find what locations `emerge` polls to determine what packages are available? For example, many of the ebuilds on my systems are in nonstandard locations, but `emerge` finds them anyway, so I'm attempting to determine how `emerge` builds it's list of available software versions.

Comment: Maybe `emerge --info =foo*` or with --search instead or something like that from the [atom syntax](http://dev.gentoo.org/~zmedico/portage/doc/man/emerge.1.html)?

Comment: You need to read up on `man portage`  Look for the `PORTDIR` Variable.  The location of your Portage Tree is determined by the setting of that variable As a shortcut try `ls ${PORTDIR}`

Comment: @inetplumber care to select an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I would recommend lkraav's solution, here is another way:

```
$ ls /usr/portage/app-portage/eix/
ChangeLog  eix-0.25.5.ebuild  eix-0.29.6.ebuild  eix-0.30.1.ebuild
Manifest   eix-0.29.3.ebuild  eix-0.30.0.ebuild  metadata.xml
```

this will of course only give you list of all ebuilds available for eix in the portage tree (without all the nice info which eix does provide).
If you are using layman more ebuilds will be available in overlays (basically in other folders).

Comment: ls -1 perhaps gives a better one-column view for this.

Comment: I like this method in combination with knowing the system's PORTDIR locations.

Comment: This method doesn't provide information on what's installed, which binary packages are built, etc

Comment: `/usr/portage/` is an older location where portage stored its build information. In 2023, you would want `/var/db/repos/gentoo/`

Answer (score 13):

Another way would be to list available keywords with equery, this will also show the versions available.

```
$ [-] equery y pidgin
Keywords for net-im/pidgin:
             |                             | u   |  
             | a a   a           p     s   | n   |  
             | l m   r h i m m   p s   p   | u s | r
             | p d a m p a 6 i p c 3   a x | s l | e
             | h 6 r 6 p 6 8 p p 6 9 s r 8 | e o | p
             | a 4 m 4 a 4 k s c 4 0 h c 6 | d t | o
-------------+-----------------------------+-----+-------
   2.10.9    | + + + o ~ + o o + + o o + + | o 0 | gentoo
[I]2.10.9-r1 | ~ + ~ o + ~ o o + ~ o o ~ + | o   | gentoo
```

Answer (score 7):

I would've expected `emerge --search` to provide this functionality, alas it only seems to show latest version.

```
$ [-] emerge --search eix
Searching...    
[ Results for search key : eix ]
[ Applications found : 1 ]

*  app-portage/eix
      Latest version available: 0.29.3
      Latest version installed: 0.29.3
      Size of files: 536 kB
      Homepage:      http://eix.berlios.de
      Description:   Search and query ebuilds, portage incl. local settings, ext. overlays, version changes, and more
      License:       GPL-2
```

So to answer your question: I've been using `eix` for so long, I don't really remember what I did before.

```
$ [-] eix eix$ -c
[I] app-portage/eix
     Available versions:  0.25.5{tbz2} 0.29.3{tbz2} ~0.29.6 ~0.30.0 ~0.30.1 {clang debug +dep doc nls optimization security sqlite strong-optimization strong-security swap-remote tools zsh-completion LINGUAS="de ru"}
     Installed versions:  0.29.3{tbz2}(10:44:38 07.09.2013)(dep nls -clang -debug -doc -optimization -security -sqlite -strong-optimization -strong-security -swap-remote -tools -zsh-completion LINGUAS="-de -ru")
     Homepage:            http://eix.berlios.de
     Description:         Search and query ebuilds, portage incl. local settings, ext. overlays, version changes, and more
```

Comment: I absolutely will second `eix` as the Goto Tool. +1

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way and the one I use 90% of the time:

```
equery list -po [package_name]
```

Comment: This is by far the simplest solution. Did exactly what I needed when the default version of `socat` was removed from [http://distfiles.gentoo.org/distfiles/](http://distfiles.gentoo.org/distfiles/)